# Click Anywhere In TableViewCell and Focus On TextField

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a custom tableviewcell with a label and a textfield.  Right now if I click on the cell to edit the textfield, it only focuses on it if I click within the bounds of the textfield.  Is there a way for me to click anywhere in the cell and immediately have it focus on the textfield, even if I click on the label?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tableView delegate, implement this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

Inside that method, get a reference to the selected tableViewCell using `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and then call `becomeFirstResponder` on the tableViewCell's textField.